# Infinite digest loop with function call in ng-src

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem with function call in ng-src field. I obtain an infinite digest loop. Here is the code:

The template

```
<div class="col-md-4" data-ng-repeat="room in roomsAvailable">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img data-ng-src="{{getBetterSizeAvailableImageUrl(room.RoomImages.RoomImage.url)}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the controller

```
$scope.getBetterSizeAvailableImageUrl = function(url) {
    selectBetterSizeAvailable(url).then(function(selectedSize) {
        return $filter('sizeSelector')(url, selectedSize);
    });
};
```

where selectBetterSizeAvailable is a function which return an available size and sizeSelector filter just returns the new url corresponding to the selected size.

Here is an example for undestanding what my function is doing.
I give it address/121315_small.jpg and it is watching for the better size available: if address/121315_verybig.jpg is not available then it tries address/121315_big.jpg, if it this url is not available then it displays the address/121315_small.jpg by default.

Comment: using filter with ajax, that will mess..everytime it gets called when digest cycle run

Comment: This sounds like something that should be done server-side instead. [Server-side code can tell you if a file exists or not almost instantly](http://adaptive-images.com/); client-side code has to do a round trip again and again.

Comment: @Blazemonger actually I have no way to do it server side since the url is obtained from an API. Since this API does not provide a good way to know if a greater size is available, I am forced to do some bad trick. But the selectBetterSizeAvailable is working well since I use it in another part of my code without any problem.

Comment: @pankajparkar I am using filter only for having a simplified way to select a size in a template like `url  | sizeSelector:big` but it does not matter, it could be a call to a basic function like  `return getUrl(url, selectedSize)` which would return the url corresponding to the selectedSize.